# How to make test class read data from target/ and not target/test-classes Java

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a Java project that when I build doing a `mvn clean install` command from the command line, it generates an output target folder.

I have a JUnit test class which takes it's test data from this target folder. When running this test class directly (right click Testclass.java > Run As > Junit Test) works fine since the target folder has already been generated.

However to when I do a `mvn clean` (which clears out the target folder and my test data as well) then do a `mvn clean install` I get a test failure. Because the test is trying to read from target/test-classes/pdf-content and not from target/pdf-content

How can I make my Testclass read test data from `target/` and not `target/test-classes` ?

Edit:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
<artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>unpack and rename content</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
<configuration>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <source>
        import com.cg.fs.common.FileUtil
        import com.cg.fs.common.ZipUtil
        import com.cg.fs.common.StringUtil

        com.services.fs.common.logging.LoggerFactory.setLogger("com.services.fs.common.logging.SystemOutLogger")
        com.services.fs.common.logging.FSLogger.setMinimal(true)
        buildHelper = new BuildHelper()

        output = new File("target")
        pdfContent = new File("target/pdf-content")

        // unzip tt intermediate thing
        List ttZip = FileUtil.discoverFiles(output, true, "production-content-.*\\.zip")
        assert ttZip.size() == 1, "Did not find expected number of content zip " + ttZip.size()
        println "Unzipping " + ttZip.get(0)
        ZipUtil.unzipToDisk(ttZip.get(0))

        // move it to pdf content
        List content = FileUtil.discoverDirectories(output, "production-content-.*-intermediate", true)
        assert tContent.size() == 1, "Did not find expected number of contents " + tContent.size()
        println "Moving " + tContent.get(0) + " to " + pdfContent
        success = FileUtil.copy(tContent.get(0), pdfContent)
        assert success, "Could not copy content"

        // move pdf content
        List fpsContent = FileUtil.discoverDirectories(output, “ls-production-content.*", true)
        assert fpsContent.size() == 1, "Did not find expected number of ls contents " + fpsContent.size()
        println "Moving " + fpsContent.get(0) + " to target/pdf-content"
        success = FileUtil.copy(fpsContent.get(0), pdfContent)
        assert success, "Could not copy pdf content"

        // rename to not be unsupported
        List unsupportedDirs = FileUtil.discoverDirectories(pdfContent, "_unsupported_.*", true)
        println "Renaming _unsupported content: " + unsupportedDirs
        for (File file : unsupportedDirs) {
        file.renameTo(new File(file.getParentFile(), file.getName().replace("_unsupported_", "")))
        }
    </source>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the question in reverse: you don't want the `maven-surefire-plugin` to read from `target` instead of `target/test-classes`. What you really want to do is to add your files as test resources of the project.

For static resources, this goes under `src/test/resources`. The `maven-resources-plugin` will copy those resources to `target/test-classes` by default.

For generated resources, you can use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-test-resource`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-resource-mojo.html) goal to add your generated content as a test resource. If they are generated under `target/pdf-content`, you can have:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-resource</id>
      <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/pdf-content</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will add all files under the folder `target/pdf-content` as a test resource in the root of the classpath. If they need to be in a specified package, you can add a `<targetPath>` to the configuration and they will be available under the specified `targetPath`. Note that the plugin is bound to the `generate-test-resources` phase so you need to make sure that the generation of those resources happens before (for example, by declaring before in the POM with the phase `generate-test-resources`).

Comment: I struggle with maven, I avoid messing with my pom. So under `<targetPath><!-- path to put the test resources --></targetPath>` what exactly would I put? src/test/resources?

Comment: @arabian_albert Okay I edited then. You can leave it. You only need it if you want the resources in a specified package. By default, it'll be at the root of the classpath.

Comment: Say I did want it in a specified package, what would I have put under targetPath? I want to embrace maven I just don't think I understand it properly

Comment: @arabian_albert Embracing Maven, you're making my day even brighter :D. For example, if they should be under the package `foo.bar`, you would have `<targetPath>foo/bar</targetPath>`.

Comment: You seem to have a way of influencing people ;) What if I'm using a default package? Example under src/test/java I have Testclass.java would I just put Testclass under target path?

Comment: You're confusing directory structure with the classpath structure. `src/test/java` is a source folder. Meaning that for Maven, the classpath starts there. The same goes for `src/test/resources`: this is just the folder structure, the whole test classpath is the addition of what is under `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources`. Example: if your class `Testclass.java` under `src/test/java` wants to access a resource `Testresource` under `src/test/resources`, it would access with `/Testresource` because the resource is at the root.

Comment: @arabian_albert If the resource is under `src/test/resources/foo/bar`, you'd access it with `/foo/bar/Testresource`. This is what the `<targetPath>` simulates.